# VHDL component output returns zeros

Tags: vhdl

I'm writing something in VHDL about an essay and I'm facing a strange situation. I've written some components, simulated and tested them, and everything seems to works fine. However, when simulating the top entity, I'm getting zeros as a result! Please take a look at the following listings:

**Top Entity:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity foobar is
  port ( data_i : in std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
             sum_12bit_o : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
            );
end foobar;

architecture Behavioral of foobar is

--Declare components
component four_10bit_word_adder is
    port( --Input signals
            a_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
            b_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
            c_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
            d_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
            cin: in std_logic;
            --Output signals
            val12bit_out: out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
    );
end component;

-- Signal declaration
signal int: std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal intdata: std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);

begin
    intdata <= data_i; --DEBUG
        U1: four_10bit_word_adder port map (intdata(39 downto 30), intdata(29 downto 20), 
                                                        intdata(19 downto 10), intdata(9 downto 0),
                                               '0', int);

end Behavioral;
```

**four_10bit_word_adder:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity four_10bit_word_adder is

generic (
    bits: integer := 10
  );

port( --Input signals
        a_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        b_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        c_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        d_byte_in: in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        cin: in std_logic;
        --Output signals
        val12bit_out: out std_logic_vector(bits+1 downto 0)
);

end four_10bit_word_adder;

architecture Behavioral of four_10bit_word_adder is

-- Component Declaration

component compressor_4_2 is
    port(a,b,c,d,cin : in std_logic; 
          cout, sum, carry : out std_logic
          );
end component;

--------------------------------------------------------+
component generic_11bit_adder
port (
    A:  in  std_logic_vector(10 downto 0); --Input A
    B:  in  std_logic_vector(10 downto 0); --Input B
    CI: in  std_logic;                           --Carry in
    O:  out std_logic_vector(10 downto 0); --Sum
    CO: out std_logic                            --Carry Out
  );
end component;
--------------------------------------------------------+

-- Declare internal signals
signal int: std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0); -- int(8) is the final Cout signal
signal byte_out: std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
signal carry: std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
signal int11bit: std_logic_vector(bits downto 0);
-- The following signals are necessary to produce concatenated inputs for the 10-bit adder.
-- See the paper for more info. 
signal Concat_A: std_logic_vector(bits downto 0);
signal Concat_B: std_logic_vector(bits downto 0);
signal co : std_logic;

begin

    A0: compressor_4_2 port map (a_byte_in(0), b_byte_in(0), 
                                c_byte_in(0), d_byte_in(0),
                                '0', int(0), byte_out(0), carry(0));
    instances: for i in 1 to bits-1 generate
        A: compressor_4_2 port map (a_byte_in(i), b_byte_in(i), 
                                             c_byte_in(i), d_byte_in(i), int(i-1),
                                             int(i), byte_out(i), carry(i));
    end generate;

    R9: generic_11bit_adder port map (Concat_A, Concat_B, '0', int11bit, co);

Concat_A <= int(8) & byte_out;
Concat_B <= carry & '0';

process (co)
begin
    if (co = '1') then 
        val12bit_out <= '1' & int11bit;
    else
        val12bit_out <= '0' & int11bit;
    end if; 
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**4:2 Compressor**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity compressor_4_2 is

    port(a,b,c,d,cin : in std_logic; 
          cout, sum, carry : out std_logic
);

end compressor_4_2;

architecture Behavioral of compressor_4_2 is

-- Internal Signal Definitions
signal stage_1: std_logic;

begin

stage_1 <= d XOR (b XOR c);
cout <= NOT((b NAND c) AND (b NAND d) AND (c NAND d));
sum <= (a XOR cin) XOR stage_1;
carry <= NOT((a NAND cin) AND (stage_1 NAND cin) AND (a NAND stage_1));

end Behavioral;
```

**Generic 11-bit Adder:**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity generic_11bit_adder is
  generic (
    bits: integer := 11
  );
  port (
    A:  in  std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
    B:  in  std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
    CI: in  std_logic;
    O:  out std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
    CO: out std_logic
  );
end entity generic_11bit_adder;

architecture Behavioral of generic_11bit_adder is
begin

process(A,B,CI)

  variable sum:         integer;

  -- Note: we have one bit more to store carry out value.
  variable sum_vector:  std_logic_vector(bits downto 0); 

begin

  -- Compute our integral sum, by converting all operands into integers.

  sum := conv_integer(A) + conv_integer(B) + conv_integer(CI);

  -- Now, convert back the integral sum into a std_logic_vector, of size bits+1

  sum_vector := conv_std_logic_vector(sum, bits+1);

  -- Assign outputs
  O <= sum_vector(bits-1 downto 0);

  CO <=  sum_vector(bits); -- Carry is the most significant bit

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I've tried a ton of things, but without any success. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong? Sorry for the long question and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your process to generate `val12bit_out` in your `four_10bit_word_adder` entity.  It's missing an input.

Also, there are several other issues.  Fixing this one issue will not fix everything.  But once you fix it, I think things will be a lot more clear.

Comment: I've changed that particular chunk of code, from using **process** and **if** statement to using **when** and it worked. What was the input that was missing? I'd like to ask you also, what kind of issues have you detected and what are your suggestions to correct them?

Comment: I fixed one more issue about the carry. It was wired to the wrong signal (int(8) instead of int(9)). Thank you very much for pointing the right direction. If you have any suggestions about the code, I 'd like to hear them.